# WebApps Birthday Celebration?

Tags: discussion

Did you know WebApps' anniversary of its graduation is coming up on **30 September**? Congratulations!

How about a fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events area a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) or at the [**Unix & Linux Birthday Bash**](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/a-contest-to-cleanup-old-abandoned-questions) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention through your moderator team! We're really interested in community-led initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “Let's go!”

Either way, congratulations on making it two years. :)

Comment: One really cool thing that one of our sites has done is organize an analog-space meetup. Feel free to get creative!

Comment: Only three days to go and still no activity - I know WebApps isn't the most meta-active mob, but any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It's sad but it's going to take a bit longer for a community led initiative unless we can keep our chat room active or bring us together in some other format. Based on some ideas flying around from JohnC, I've made a new post talking about how to clean up the finer details for a

[Clean up a thon contest!](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/clean-up-a-thon-contest)

> Cleaning's an art. My mop is my paintbrush.

If I can get more input from the community that would be great. If not I will just send a draft to SE by the end of next week.