# Clean up a thon contest!

Tags: discussion, contest, clean-up

Kicking off the activity by introducing an idea brought up by JohnC.

### Clean up a thon!!!

[image: The Janitor can be cool sometimes...]

> Cleaning's an art. My mop is my paintbrush.

Our answer rate has dropped to 87% which may seem great but it's pretty low in the league of SE sites. So to counter this we will try to set up a contest similar to Unix: [A contest to cleanup old, abandoned questions](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/a-contest-to-cleanup-old-abandoned-questions).

**Rules**

So the following set are actions we *can* do for the contest:

- Answer an old question well enough to receive the Revival or Necromancer badge (Drop the question in [Google-Fu](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu) and hopefully some of us can help by either voting or explaining what's missing from the answer to make it great)
- Vote to close a question (or flag close vote) that was asked before 2012.

(Any more ideas?)

The breakdown from Unix seems reasonable:

> We'll break it down as follows:
>
> - 4 points for each [Revival](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/195/revival) badge
> - 5 points for each [Necromancer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/17/necromancer) badge (note that you'll possibly already have Revival as well)
> - 1 point for each closed question

**Prizes**

The prizes *should* relate in some way to Web Applications (e.g. a subscription to a Web App).

Since the SE Clothing Store is closed maybe we can start looking at getting Web App specific clothing/swag?

What do you think?

(I'll be in [Google Fu](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu) if you want to throw around ideas, but try not to take too long, I would like to send something concrete to SE Staff by next week Friday 12th October.)

Comment: Can you join the contest and choose to not be in the running?

Comment: Sure, it could be the same as giving up your prize

Comment: Looks good to me! I thought SE still had swag for giveaways, just running the store was too much hassle. Would certainly be good to get unanswered back under 1000!

Comment: @JohnC SE still has swag, I've spoken to them and they will be able to offer for the contest

Comment: IMO this question should be closed as it a call for action with deadline that was more than 24 months ago.

Comment: This is an archived post that no longer applies.