# What should your top prize be?

Tags: discussion, contest

Your moderator team has put together a [great little cleanup contest](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/clean-up-a-thon-contest) for y'all to celebrate your anniversary!

Right now, the suggestion for the top prize is an annual subscription to a webapp. There's some concern about this on the Community Team, so I'm soliciting alternatives.

Parameters:

- Something tangible is preferred
- Prize can cost ***up to*** U.S. $100
- Amazon-available items are preferred

Please post ideas as separate answers. Let's see what y'all can come up with!

Comment: i’m still waiting for the one from last year to arrive. (See the comments to [this answer](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/a/1115/1512).)

Comment: I guess the winner(s) will get to choose between the two...?

Comment: @Aarthi sounds fine

Answer (score 6):

[This cloud pillow](http://www.etsy.com/listing/98445054/grey-cloud-pillow-organic-cotton-fabric) is adorable, affordable, unique, and thematic! I contacted the seller and s/he said they would be able/willing to embroider the Webapps.SE logo onto it.

[image]

Comment: flufffffffffyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Comment: @Sathya [for your enjoyment](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nSINQJlSTc).

Answer (score 5):

Corsair's [nigh indestructible flash drive](http://amzn.com/B006B7R8ZG) is a good top prize. This thing can basically survive anything, is pretty snazzy-looking, and is a great way to back up important files that would otherwise only be in the ~the cloud~.

[image]